# How do I filter a certain column, removing repeated data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to return the weights to a histogram, but with the names only appearing once.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bob', 'Simon', 'Bill', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Bob'],
                   'Weight': [70, 72, 71, 67, 67, 70]})
```

This:

```
Bob    70
Simon  72
Bill   71
Mary   67
```

Comment: If 'Bob' appears 2 times with a different weight what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use `drop_duplicates`:

```
out = df.drop_duplicates(['Name', 'Weight'])
print(out)

# Output
    Name  Weight
0    Bob      70
1  Simon      72
2   Bill      71
3   Mary      67
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `groupby`:

```py
df.groupby('Name')['Weight'].mean()
```

If you want to take just the first data point available for each name:

```py
df.groupby('Name')['Weight'].first()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `groupby` function with aggregate function as `mean`

The data looks like this

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bob', 'Simon', 'Bill', 'Mary', 'Mary', 'Bob'], 'Weight': [70, 72, 71, 67, 67, 70]})
>>> print(df)

Name  Weight
0    Bob      70
1  Simon      72
2   Bill      71
3   Mary      67
4   Mary      67
5    Bob      70

>>> df2 = df.groupby(['Name']).mean()

>>> print(df2)

Name  Weight
0   Bill      71
1    Bob      70
2   Mary      67
3  Simon      72
```

Convert `Name` index column to a column and add a `RangeIndex`

```
>>> df2['Name'] = df2.index
>>> df2 = df2[['Name', 'Weight']]
>>> df2.set_index(pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=len(df2), step=1), inplace=True)
>>> print(df2)

Name  Weight
0   Bill      71
1    Bob      70
2   Mary      67
3  Simon      72
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```python
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name', 'Weight'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```python
>>>  Name  Weight
0    Bob      70
1  Simon      72
2   Bill      71
3   Mary      67
```

Comment: Sorry but you should read already posted answers before :)